# Add multiple pictures to UIViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, photos, image

I Want to add four different pictures to a ViewController. I am able to add one picture. And when i try to add another picture in a different Imageview, the same pictures appears on both the imageviews. Could anyone please give an idea of how to add unique pictures.

```
 - (void)imagePickerControllerUIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfoNSDictionary *)info {
       if(choosePhoto1){

       NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button1");

       theimageView1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else if(choosePhoto2) {
         NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button2");

         theimageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

         [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include some of your code.

Comment: Do you mind putting in some code?

Answer (score 0):

Add some code ... simply from your description nobody can help you.
The educated guess is that your not creating a new object each time you add or your passing the same reference several times

---

Form your code I would say your setting twice the same image:

in both cases you use @"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"

so if info is the same object both times its normal your getting the same image

Comment: - (void)imagePickerControllerUIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfoNSDictionary *)info {
    if(choosePhoto1){

       NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button1");

       theimageView1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else if(choosePhoto2) {
         NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button2");

         theimageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

         [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }

}

Answer (score 0):

If you created the .xib in interface builder, be sure to go into it and ensure that you've wired up each imageview to the IBOutlets for their views and not the same one for all.